# BroadcastReceiver waking up Service when phone goes idle

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a long running service. When the device goes idle and CPU sleeps the service gets paused. However when I declare a static (in manifest) `BroadcastReceiver` the phone will execute the `onReceive()` method even when asleep.

I would like to know how to wakeup my Service and pass some information to it from the `BroadcastReceiver`. Im completely new to Android development so don't know anything about the IPC in Android.

I read about bound services but I think this is not my case as I need to service to run in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your BroadcastReceiver do the following to start MyService:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
...
Intent svc = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
svc.setAction("some_action");
context.startService(svc);
```

Replace:

- MyService: with the actual service class name
- "some_action": with some action to be passed to the service (a
  String)

Comment: So in case the service is already running, doing this means that the onStartCommand in my service will be called again with this Intent so I can process everything in the onStartCommand method?

Comment: exactly, you can process everything in the onStartCommand method

Comment: @muslidrikk what's related to system idle?